# How to add custome template in Vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to have my custom template added whenever I create a .java file.
What modifications do I need to do to my .vimrc?

I've tried mapping and stuff but, that didn't help .

Comment: Probably this SE site is more suitable for such questions: https://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Often, people use a snippet plugin like [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) for this purpose.

But in fact snippets provide much more structure than you require.

You can accomplish the same thing by adding an `autocmd` to your .vimrc. To do this:

1. Write your desired template file. I'll suppose it's called `java.template`. Put it in a reasonable spot, like `~/.vim/templates/java.template`.
2. Add the line `autocmd BufNewFile *.java 0r ~/.vim/templates/java.template` to your `.vimrc`.

What this line does is detect when a new java buffer (or at least a buffer whose filename ends in `.java`) is opened, it reads your template file and places it at the first line.

This used to be a common vim idiom. You can read more about this approach in vim's documentation at `:h template`.